# Iterate over JavaScript object with index

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop over a JavaScript object in ES6.

```
 for (let [value, index] of object) {
    do something with rest
    if (index >= 1) {
       // do something with first item
    }
  }
```

It works fine, although when I try to use index to get the first item it returns an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
```

Any ideas on how to loop over an object with index? thanks

Comment: Do you realize that properties have no specific order so an index really doesn't mean anything for properties of an object?  I suspect that this is just the wrong way to do whatever you're trying to do.  You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of property names and then iterate that and there will be an index then, though again, it's probably not meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I will try and change the object to an array which sounds more logical if I need to get first item.

Comment: Yes, an array makes more sense and then your `for/of` loop will work as you want.

Comment: What is your `object`? Please post the whole code that throws this error (it suggest that your `object` is iterable, but the elements are not).

Answer (score 59):

*This is just meant to be an addition to jonas w's solutions.*

If you need the key of the current value:

```js
const object = {a:2, b:4, c:6, d:8};

for (const [index, [key, value]] of Object.entries(Object.entries(object))) {
  console.log(`${index}: ${key} = ${value}`);
}

Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
  console.log(`${index}: ${key} = ${value}`);
});
```

Of course, you can leave out the `key` at any time:

```js
const object = {a:2, b:4, c:6, d:8};

for (const [index, [, value]] of Object.entries(Object.entries(object))) {
  console.log(`${index}: ${value}`);
}

Object.entries(object).forEach(([, value], index) => {
  console.log(`${index}: ${value}`);
});
```

Comment: Simple hack to do it.

Answer (score 31):

Simply count the index:

```
let index = 0;
for (let value of object) {
  //do something with rest
  if (index >= 1) {
    // do something with the third and following items
  }
  index++;
}
```

Or if you really want to use object destructuring ( i dont know why ) its a bit more complicated:

```
let entries = Object.entries(object);

for(let [index, [key, value]] of entries.entries()){
 //...
}
```

or:

```
for(let [index,value] of Object.values(object).entries()){
  //...
}
```

But i dont know why youre not using a simple forEach?:

```
Object.values(obj).forEach((value, index)=> /*...*/);
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your answer. But I was hoping there was a cleaner and neater way to do this in ES6.

Comment: @londonfed shure there are a few approaches.

Comment: Ok a simple forEach sounds like best way to go. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

`index`, `key`:

```js
for (const [index, key] of Object.keys(object).entries()) {
  // ...
}
```

`index`, `value`:

```js
for (const [index, value] of Object.values(object).entries()) {
  // ...
}
```

`index`, `key`, `value`:

```js
for (const [index, [key, value]] of Object.entries(object).entries()) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just count the index:

```js
let index = 0;
for (let value of object) {
  if (index === 1) {
    // do something with idx 1
  }
  // do something with the rest...
  index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 23,
  city: 'Mexico',
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key, '=>', value)
}
```