# How can I get the element that is clicked on with a click handler added in a forEach?

Tags: javascript

I need to detect element count number

I have 10 poster elements and I have a `forEach` loop

I need the poster number that I clicked on, for example if I click on the seventh poster `posternumber` should be `7`

```
    poster.forEach(p => {
            p.addEventListener('click',function(){
                videoTag.src = xResult[movieLanguageUrl][/*posternumber*/]; 
           });
    });
```

Comment: @Liam i know how for loop works but i need same inside forEach loop.thanks for your comment.

Comment: forEach callback have such parameters: `currentValue`, `index`, `array`. So, you can use `index` parameter as `posternumber`. And, more exactly - `index + 1`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over JavaScript object with index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251605/iterate-over-javascript-object-with-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the index value on the second parameter of the `forEach` function and it should work:

```
poster.forEach((p, index) => {
    p.addEventListener('click', () => {
        videoTag.src = xResult[movieLanguageUrl][index + 1]; 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the signatur of your `forEach` consumer function. The secound argument is the index.

```
poster.forEach((p, idx) => {
    p.addEventListener('click',function(){
        videoTag.src = xResult[movieLanguageUrl][idx]; 
    });
});
```

Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) link.

Comment: or `idx + 1` if the seventh poster starts from index 1 ;-)

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi I think its a typo of the op. If the seventh post is be clicked he want the index of the sevent poster. But maybee the op can tell us?